# How to: Refresh AngularJS Route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a Typescript SPA project through Visual Studio and I'm using AngularJS to handle the routing. Here's my config...

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(($routeProvider, $locationProvider) => {
$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "/pages/index/index.html"
    })
    .when("/about", {
        templateUrl: "/pages/about/about.html"
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

This is working fine, as it makes the URLs look how I want. However, when I go to refresh the page, I get an error 404 or error 403 depending on whether it's the main page or the about page. How do I go about making it so it refreshes to the correct page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's is a server-side thing, your server is handling your entire url as if it was a normal path in the server. You must configure this to target `index.html` always otherwise your server will try to find the `www.myserver.com/about` page. There for, it will produce a 404 status code because your url couldn't be found or is forbidden to access in case of a directory.

Comment: So I would have to create a separate route for every single page I decide to make server-side? How would you recommend doing this server-side, IIS, Apache, or something else?

Comment: @chuloon you must configure your server-side technology to always target the index page independent of which url is being requested. Which server-side handler are you using? Apache, IIS, node.js?

Comment: I'm actually very new to using anything back end. My entire career has been based on front end technology, so I haven't wired up anything. However, I am using firebase for my database, but that's probably not what I should be using for this problem. I'll do some research into it all, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction!